# Combining divisibility with congruences

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

If we assume that    $x^2 - xy + y^2 \equiv 0 \pmod n$
Then                 $x^2 + y^2 \equiv xy \pmod n$
If                   $(x,y,n)=1$.

Then we can observe that neither x nor y can divide the left side of the second equation, but both can divide the right side of the equation; therefore, can we say that
$$x^2 + y^2 \not = xy \pmod n$$
and
$$x^2 - xy + y^2 \not = 0 \pmod n\;?$$

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that doesn't work.  Consider the counterexample

$$3^2-3(5)+5^2=19\equiv0\pmod{19}$$

Answer (score 1):

If $\,(x,y)=1,\,$ $\,n = x^2\!-xy+y^2$ then $(x,y,n) = (x,y) = 1\,$ but $\,x^2\!-xy+y^2 = n \equiv 0\pmod n$

You can use this counterexample (or numerical instances thereof) to help debug your attempted proof: $ $ an error occurs on the first line where your proof fails on the counterexample. [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+concrete+debug) for some concrete examples of such proof debugging.